# Arduino + multiple ultrasonic sensors + interference

Tags: arduino

I have two buggies moving around a track, both of which use ultrasonic measurement modules to detect obstacles in their paths and are controlled by Arduino microcontrollers. The two ultrasonic sensors operate at the same frequency and this frequency cannot be changed. The two ultrasonic sensors are interfering with each other. How can I reduce this interference, or prevent it, by adding something to the Arduino code. The hardware cannot be changed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

There are in general six ways to reduce interference between two channels (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing) - two of which don't apply to sound. That leaves you with four:

```
space      - don't operate in the same space (e.g. cell towers): not applicable for you
frequency  - (e.g. channels) you said you can't change that
time       - don't operate at the same time
code       - send out different amplitude patterns
```

In a sense, "code" is a bit like "time", but more complicated. With "time", you try to time it so the two transducers don't transmit at the same time. With "code", they send complex pulse sequences and use these to eliminate the interference.

I think your best bet (simple, but effective) is "time". This is going to depend a little bit on the frequency of update that you need, but you could make one buggy the "master", sending a short chirp every 100 ms (say); then have the second buggy wait until it hears the master chirp, and send its own pulse 50 ms later (when it knows the other buggy will be quiet). In this way each will have 10 updates per second, but they will not interfere.

To be more robust, the "slave" buggy could decide (after not hearing a pulse from the "master") to send its own pulse after 100 ms - this way it can operate when there is only one buggy present. And they could in fact each use this algorithm - then there is no "master" and "slave" and they have the same code (usually a good idea). As a final tweak, if you make this "wait for n ms" interval random, you will have implemented a version of "carrier sense multiple access with collision detection" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection

Good luck.